# Why is String not a value?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val a = Int
a: Int.type = object scala.Int

scala> val a = String
<console>:11: error: object java.lang.String is not a value
       val a = String
               ^
```

Why didn't scala create a thin wrapper around `java.lang.String` in order to make `String` a value? Isn't it very restrictive when one of the main types (`String`) cannot be used in expressions or passed to / returned from functions?

Comment: *Isn't it very restrictive when one of the main types (String) cannot be used in expressions or passed to / returned from functions?* Why would you assume that? Not sure what the binding of `String` to a value is trying to convey

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm used to dynamically-typed languages (where I might for example want to verify the type of something in run-time). I guess in static languages it's not as useful / common to store a type in a variable (since the types are all known at compile time)? That said, `val a = Int` is valid in scala; so there might be at least some use for it?

Comment: You can do `val tpe = typeOf[String]` or `val cls = classOf[String]`. And `val a = Int` is valid because Int is a companion object to Int type.

Comment: @adamwy That answers my question; I assume for performance reasons it was better to separate companion object to `String` type from the `String` type itself?

Comment: @max You can't verify that something is of type `Int` using `val a = Int`. The `Int` object simply contains some useful methods that work with `Int`s. It can't be used to do anything reflecty with `Int`s. You'd want `typeof[Int]` for that (and as has been pointed out, the same works for strings).

Comment: There is probably no reason to have `String` companion, since all useful methods are in `StringOps` implicit wrapper. For `Int` I think it exists only to store `MaxValue` and `MinValue` somewhere.

Comment: @max String doesn't have a companion object because there no one came up with any useful methods that such an object should contain. There are generally no empty companion objects in Scala. Nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @adamwy Just for the sake of being pedantic, what you get as `tpe` or `cls` is not a Scala type, it's an object (probably a singleton) of some type, e.g. `Class[String]`.

Comment: @max Types in Scala exist in a parallel universe, let's say 'compiler universe', while values are from 'runtime universe'. While there are tools to get a type at runtime, none of them are technically required for a statically typed language. What are you trying to do? Isn't pattern matching enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... In Scala `class`'s can have companion objects.

And that companion object for any `class A` is actually an instance of `A.type`.

So... when you do,

```
val i = Int
```

What you get is `companion object` of `class Int` which is an instance of `Int.type`

Keep in mind that `Int` is still not a value... this thing that you have is not `Int`. It is also not an instance of `Int`. It is an instance of `Int.type`.

But as far as `String` is concerned... it is defined as an Alias for the corresponding `java.lang.String` from the Java world and thus has no such `companion object`. And hence the `val` assignment does not work with it.

As for why `String` is not wrapped in Scala. There can be many reasons for this. But one main reason is because there was no need for that.

Scala wanted to be have `pure` object hierarchy such that everything is an object and inherits from the same root `Any`. And Java has basic-types like `int`, `long` etc... which are not objects... and this created a need to wrap them into `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question probably turns on a misapprehension about reifying a type, the following suggests why you can select Java statics as though they were members of a companion object, even though there is no such object:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis
res0: Long = 1483263161912

scala> java.lang.System
<console>:12: error: object java.lang.System is not a value
       java.lang.System
                 ^

scala> java.lang.System.toString
<console>:12: error: value toString is not a member of object System
Note that System extends Any, not AnyRef.
Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
       java.lang.System.toString
                        ^

scala>
```